# NestJS validate POST body when it's other than object type

Tags: nestjs

I need to validate a list of emails (array of strings) that are passed via `POST`. Using something like validation pipes and `class-validator` would be awesome (however in the official docs I only found examples of objects validation through DTOs and validation of primitive types but for `GET` requests).

Here is how my method looks like in the controller:

```ts
@Post()
async submit(@Body() emails: string[]) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just being passed directly like that, then there's not much you can do besides implement a custom pipe. If you are able to change the payload structure I would suggest it to something like

```js
export class PostDTO {
  @IsEmail({ each: true })
  emails: string[]
}
```

And use

```js
@Post()
async submit(@Body() { emails }: PostDTO) {}
```

so that Nest's `ValidationPipe` can read the metadata of the post.